# Expanding plane size while keeping existing vertices

Tags: workflow

This is a workflow question. What is the fastest way to get the plane on the right starting with the plane on the left? I think in 3ds max you can select the vertex I have selected in the picture and "drag" out the plane, creating a plane inside a plane. Can you do this in blender? I know you can start with a larger plane and inset (I) but there must be a more efficient way.

[image]

Comment: I believe the tool you are looking for is the extrude tool: http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html?highlight=extrude

Comment: So you can use the extrude tool to expand a plane laterally? I don't see it on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way *(albeit not the best)* of all current answers is to just extrude and scale a bit by some eyeballing based on object size then move the extrusion into place with <kbd>G</kbd>. No fancy 3d cursor tricks and keyboard shortcuts/tools needed. ;)

The reason it snaps into place when freely moving is because snapping is on (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) and set to move in increments which is based on the grid.

[image]

Comment: @ iKlsR : Looks like you are using a snap to ensure alignment of the new geometry. You should add that to your answer. Simply 'eyeballing' it will likely lead to unsatisfactory results.

Comment: @MikeMetcalf Ah, yes, added. Snapping is on and set to increments by default. By eyeballing I mean when creating the extrusion, easily achievable in a couple attempts at least.

Comment: @iKlsR♦ you're a real speed demon ;). the fastest way indeed. I wonder if there'll be a possibility to do it using just scaling in the future blender releases. +1 from me.

Comment: @Gonzou When I came to Blender from max years ago, my most missed feature was the shift extrude that op mentions where you just select, hold shift and extrude. It would have done this in one step. Might be, who knows. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate method that might be useful in some circumstances. In edit mode, select one of the vertices of the plane, and from the context menu of the snap tool (<kbd>SHFT</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd>), select "Cursor to selected". Next, invert the selection (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>I</kbd>), to deselect the original vertex, and select the other three. Then set the pivot point to 3D cursor, extrude the selected vertices, and scale to the desired size.

[image]

Comment: ha! 'great minds...' and all that...

Answer (score 4):

Here is the *fastest* way:

- ensure the Pivot Center is set to '3D Cursor'
- select only the vertex at the top right
- hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> then 'Cursor to Selected', which moves the 3D Cursor to that vertex
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> which will invert your selection
- hit <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale
- hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when satisfied

This prevents the necessity of repositioning the two edge vertices.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: After reading iKlsR and Gonzou's answers I was surprised that nobody had posted this yet (it is *the* answer), well you and brasshat had.

Answer (score 3):

As cegaton said, you may achieve it using *extrude tool*. Place the cursor in the center of a plane, select 3 vertices, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude them, then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale (you may input the scale value from your numerical keyboard). Next enable the *Snapping Tool* (click the magnet icon) and change the snapping element type to *Vertex*. Select the vertices as pictured below, press <kbd>G</kbd> and input the proper axis. Move the mouse until they snap to others.
[image]

If you want to make a reverse select the whole plane (<kbd>A</kbd>), hit <kbd>W</kbd>*-->Subdivide*. Select two vertices as pictured below and press <kbd>G</kbd> twice to merge them. Select the whole mesh again, press <kbd>W</kbd>*-->Remove Doubles*. Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice to slide the selected vertices.
[image]